# Backslash become double backslash for no reason in my php string

Tags: php

Running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

PHP 7.3.17

```
$str = '\controller\welcome';
error_log("string : " . $str);
```

Output:

```
\\controller\\welcome
```

Works fine on Windows otherwise.

Comment: This may not really answer your question, but you don't need to use the `.` to concatenate inside of double quoted strings. You could just do `error_log("string : $str");` or `error_log("string : {$str}");` if you want to be more explicit that it's a variable. The only time you need to concatenate outside of the string is if the string is a single quote string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code that you've shown.

Comment: I am not getting that output ether. Works fine...

Answer (score -3):

`\` is an escape character, [read more about it here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). This is programming 101.